# python web page RE-loads generate dozens of transactions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Been working on a python website with pyramid & sqlalchemy. I recently changed the logging setup so that it is showing the filename being used, the function being used, and the line number for manually logged items. Log level DEBUG.

Initial page load runs a small handful of transactions. Depending on the page, something like < 5 of something similar to this

```
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> _commitResources >> 392 :: commit <zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager.SessionDataManager object at 0x7f984c12e6a0>
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> _commitResources >> 392 :: commit <zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager.SessionDataManager object at 0x7f984c1184a8>
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> commit >> 288 :: commit
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> __init__ >> 108 :: new transaction
```

This actually reveals another problem, probably related, which is that each page access generates 2 accesses. When writing to the db, for example, I've had to work around it by testing for the record first, otherwise the 2nd time thru will bonk on unique keys.

Anyway, If I reload the page, it generates some 40-50 `_transaction.py` calls. I haven't counted, but it's like 3-4 screen pages in the python console of this:

```
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> __init__ >> 108 :: new transaction
/opt/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/transaction/_transaction.py >> commit >> 288 :: commit
```

that's `path/to/filename.py` >> `function name()`>> line number :: message.

The site is kind of an enhanced blog. There's posts with specific content, comments on the content, and a list page for the posts. Then there's home and profile.

I say 'transactions' because the filename that appears over and over is _transaction.py. And I see that it's database related. And I would generally expect that, if anything, it would generate fewer db interactions.

The questions are

- why is it losing it's mind but *only* on a reload of all things?
- what could I look at to decipher this?
- is there some log option that can show me a more verbose internal python context? It might be a bit much but if there were a 'step' level option that'd help me narrow it down.

Comment: My guess would be a full reload loads images, javascripts and stuff, all of them are probably served via Pyramid. Each request generates a single transaction. When you visit the page "normally", only the HTML is loaded because the rest is cached. It does not explain your "double transaction" problem though... can you share your SQLAlchemy session setup and other relevant bits?

Comment: Also, the `transaction` module you're referring to is not totally database related. Basically, a "transaction" is started on every request, and is committed when request finishes without error (or rolled back on exception). The actual database interaction is is done by SQLAlchemy, and only if there are actual queries to run. To see the queries sent to the database you can enable the `echo` option in the engine configuration.